# Portable name of C++ compiler (and linker)

Tags: command, portability, compiler

cc is the POSIX name of the C compiler. Is there a general name of the C++ compiler (and linker). Notice that `g++` also adds some libraries, that will not be included when using plain gcc or ld.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX C compiler front-end is [now `c99`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html); `cc` is widely available but not guaranteed. POSIX doesn’t specify anything C++-related, so you won’t find a standardised command to invoke a C++ compiler and linker there.

Common practice (see for example [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#index-CXX)) is to rely on the `CC` and `CXX` variables. In GNU’s case the default values for those are `cc` and `g++` respectively; BSDs tend to use `cc` and `c++` (see for example [OpenBSD’s configuration](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/d1d999610aa4f5e16fd0872086b30a963fac84fe/share/mk/sys.mk#L31)). The linker is accessed through the compiler driver, and not invoked explicitly.

Comment: Most BSD systems (macOS included) uses `cc` and `c++`. macOS, FreeBSD, and NetBSD also has `c99` and `c89`, but these are missing on OpenBSD. FreeBSD and NetBSD does not seem to have a manual for `c++`.

Answer (score 0):

As for Linux most of the Makefile's I've seen over the past two decades use nothing but `gcc`/`g++`. When someone bothers to use a real linker and not GCC they normally specify `ld`. I've seen `cc` maybe once.

Most Linux distros do provide a symlink from `cc` to `gcc` but they don't if you remove GCC and install clang instead.

Not idea if it's portable, as e.g. FreeBSD has recently migrated to Clang/LVM, other BSDs continue to use GCC, Mac OS uses Clang as well. Android has its own toolchain.

I haven't used any other Unixes, so no comments.

What's your use case? Please edit your question and provide more details.